# CreateView not saving on submit, but is on UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I've been scratching my head on this for 2 days now, hoping someone can help me figure out what I am missing.

I was able to submit before, but changed something, and I can't figure out what.

When I try and add a new Client, the page just reloads, doing nothing.

But when I go and edit one that is already created (using the admin console) it works as expected.

models.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models import DateTimeField
from django.db.models import FileField
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models
from django.db import models as models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_extensions.db import fields as extension_fields

FINANCING_TYPE = (
    ('LoanPal', 'LoanPal'),
    ('Renew', 'Renew'),
    ('GreenSky', 'GreenSky'),
    ('Cash/Card/Check', 'Cash/Card/Check'),
    ('Other', 'Other - Please Note'),
)

ROOF_TYPE = (
    ('Cement Flat', 'Cement Flat'),
    ('Cement S/W', 'Cement S/W'),
    ('Composite', 'Composite'),
    ('Clay', 'Clay'),
    ('Metal', 'Metal'),
    ('Other', 'Other - Please Note'),
)

JOB_STATUS = (
    ('New', 'New'),
    ('Sent to Engineer', 'Sent to Engineer'),
    ('Installer', 'Installer'),
    ('Completed', 'Completed'),
)


class Client(models.Model):

    # Fields
    sales_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    job_status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=JOB_STATUS, default="New")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    financing_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=FINANCING_TYPE)
    contract_amount = models.IntegerField()
    contract_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to="upload/files/contracts/")
    electric_bill = models.FileField(upload_to="upload/files/electric_bills/")
    roof_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROOF_TYPE)
    edge_of_roof_picture = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Picture of Roof Edge", upload_to="upload/files/edge_of_roof_pictures/")
    rafter_picture = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Picture of Rafter/Truss", upload_to="upload/files/rafter_pictures/")
    biggest_breaker_amp = models.IntegerField()
    electric_panel_picture = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Picture of Electrical Panel", upload_to="upload/files/electric_panel_pictures/")
    electric_box_type = models.CharField(verbose_name="Top or bottom fed electric box (is there an overhead line coming in? Can you see where the electric line comes in?)", max_length=100)
    main_panel_location = models.CharField(verbose_name="Main panel location (looking at house from street)", max_length=100)
    additional_notes = models.TextField(verbose_name="Any Additional Notes?", blank=True)
    customer_informed = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Informed customer plans and placards will be mailed to them and make them available install day")
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sales_client_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.street_address
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, UpdateView, CreateView
from .models import Client
from .forms import ClientForm
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class ClientListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Client
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
            return Client.objects.filter(sales_person=self.request.user)
        else:
            return Client.objects.all()

class ClientCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class = ClientForm
    model = Client

class ClientDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Client

#    def get_object(self):
#        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
#            return get_object_or_404(Client, sales_person=self.request.user)
#        else:
#            queryset = self.get_queryset()
#            obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
#            return obj



class ClientUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Client
    form_class = ClientForm
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Client


class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'street_address', 'city', 'zipcode',
                  'phone_number', 'email_address', 'financing_type', 'contract_amount',
                  'contract_pdf', 'electric_bill', 'roof_type', 'edge_of_roof_picture',
                  'rafter_picture', 'biggest_breaker_amp', 'electric_panel_picture',
                  'electric_box_type', 'main_panel_location', 'additional_notes', 'customer_informed']
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views



urlpatterns = (
    # urls for Client
    path('clients/', views.ClientListView.as_view(), name='sales_client_list'),
    path('client/create/', views.ClientCreateView.as_view(), name='sales_client_create'),
    path('client/view/<int:pk>', views.ClientDetailView.as_view(), name='sales_client_detail'),
    path('client/update/<int:pk>', views.ClientUpdateView.as_view(), name='sales_client_update'),
)
```

client_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form|crispy}}
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Let's see your models.py?

Comment: I'm not sure what `form.subject.errors` is supposed to be. Your form doesn't have a subject field, and why would you only show errors for that field anyway? You should show `form.errors`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it was a misguided attempt to get some logging into the process, since the terminal isn't telling me anything.

I actually removed those lines immediately, didn't realize I happened to copy that bad version. Edited

Comment: @Reez0 added models.py

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get help from GinFuyou on #Django on via irc.Freenode.net

The issue was that I need to have enctype="multipart/form-data" on client_form.html

full line should be

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

This is due to having files upload to the form.